# Font size is too big on Windows 10 for some applications

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts

The font size and UI components are too big for some applications, such as VirtualBox and Krita. I can fix this on a per-application basis by changing the "high DPI settings" under the Context Menu>Properties>Compatibility tab for the shortcut, but I don't want to have to change this setting for each and every application affected. This has only started happening recently, and I don't remember making any substantial hardware or software changes.

"Settings>System>Display>Change the size of text, apps, and other items" is set to 100% - changing it to something else and back doesn't fix the issue. "Advanced scaling settings" is not set.

VirtualBox - [font too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBR0g.png)

VirtualBox - [correct font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg8s2.png)

Krita - [font too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSeOV.png)

Krita - [correct font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi2et.png)

Comment: Do you perhaps have a secondary display that is set to something higher than 100% scaling?

Comment: I'm using a laptop that's hooked up to an external display, with only the external display showing most of the time. The laptop is set to 225%, but changing it to 100% doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: It will fix the problem, after signing out and back in again.

Comment: Maybe, but the laptop monitor has a high pixel density so it may not be a viable long-term solution. I'll try it though.

Comment: Welp, looks like that was the perfect solution after all. I'll post an answer now.

Comment: The “correct” solution involves the ISV updating their software to do DPI scaling properly. Do contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My setup is a laptop connected to an external monitor. The setting located at "Settings>System>Display>Change the size of text, apps, and other items" was set to 100% for the external monitor, and 225% for the laptop monitor. I set the setting for the laptop monitor to 100% and restarted my computer (signing out and back in again may also work) and that fixed the issue. After I set it back to 225% and restarted, the font remained fixed.

Comment: If I use this, then everything becomes unbearably small on my laptop. Is there any way to modify this just for some specific programs and not others?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and searching through the internet for solutions for a few days came up nothing that the standard responses as above have indicated which does not solve the problem.  I had my company IT tried a variety of options : advance display settings, rebooting, uninstall and reinstall Office 365 and they all do not work.  Interestingly, when the IT expert login to my laptop with his own user login, the icons and fonts looked normal - which is what I wanted.  He then tried to create a new user profile for me and voila ! Problem solved.  Somehow the user profile must have been corrupted when some updates were executed - couldn't be sure what updates caused it but I suspect MS Office 365.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1102084)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a Windows issue (theme settings become broken for the current user after some manipulations with screen resolution and scale if there are several monitors attached each having different settings). Unfortunately, after Win10 Creator update all the related system fine tuning options became unavailable for users. The way to solve it for now is to gain access to such option through third-party apps (e.g. [System Font Size Changer](https://www.wintools.info/index.php/system-font-size-changer)). You'll need to run the app, move each slider to *any value other then the initial one* (18), apply settings, then move them back to 18 and press apply once again.